# Android EditText listener for cursor position change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a dialog with EditText in it. The EditText is already populated when it is created.  When the user places the cursor on or near certain parts of the text a Toast will pop up.

My problem is listening for changes in cursor position.  Another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652569/android-edittext-listener-for-cursor-position-change) asks the same question and the accepted solution was

> You can override onSelectionChanged (int selStart, int selEnd) to get notified about selection changes. If the cursor is moved, this is called as well (in this case selStart == selEnd)

[onSelectionChanged (int selStart, int selEnd)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onSelectionChanged%28int,%20int%29) is a protected method of the TextView class.  How do override it?

Comment: I've been doing this successfully in my project, but have just discovered that on some mobiles onSelectionChanged() IS called, and in others it is not being called. Both > Android 4.0 ....

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just subclass or extend the class EditText and add the following code to the newly create class:

```
@Override 
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd); // Always call
    // the super implementation, which informs the accessibility 
    // subsystem about the selection change.

    // Do ur task here.
}
```

Don't forget to add constructors to the subclass. :)

Comment: Thankyou Guru, worked well.  I have appended details of what i did to my original question if anyone is interested.

Comment: I get a `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file` when I put this in my code... Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't quite work if you can't use the subclass (for instance, listening to cursor change positions in a `SearchView`, which is a complex layout that has an `EditText` embedded in it).

Comment: @TedHopp Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36389070/170842

Comment: For anyone with @KamranAhmed 's problem: Did you implement the three required constructors? Does your xml element point at the right package in your project?

Comment: Great, so there's no reliable way to do this? Digging into the TextView code (which EditText inherits from), all the methods in the answers are the same thing, which means all of them have the same issues and may not work on some devices. I'm done

Answer (score 18):

You can actually listen to selection changes without subclassing an `EditText`. It's a little more complicated but still manageable. To do it you need to add a `SpanWatcher` to a text and handle changes of selection spans.

```
final SpanWatcher watcher = new SpanWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onSpanAdded(final Spannable text, final Object what,
      final int start, final int end) {
    // Nothing here.
  }

  @Override
  public void onSpanRemoved(final Spannable text, final Object what, 
      final int start, final int end) {
    // Nothing here.
  }

  @Override
  public void onSpanChanged(final Spannable text, final Object what, 
      final int ostart, final int oend, final int nstart, final int nend) {
    if (what == Selection.SELECTION_START) {
      // Selection start changed from ostart to nstart. 
    } else if (what == Selection.SELECTION_END) {
      // Selection end changed from ostart to nstart. 
    }
  }
};

editText.getText().setSpan(watcher, 0, 0, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Is SpanWatcher notified only about changes inside its range? Why INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE?

Comment: No, it's notified about all changes. It's `INCLUSIVE` because it shouldn't be removed when you clear the `EditText`.

Comment: Note that the watcher will be lost if you ever call `setText`.

Comment: You can avoid this by re-adding it in the `afterTextChanged` method of a `TextWatcher`.

Comment: Does not trigger when moving cursor without selecting anything (OnePlus 7, API 31).

Answer (score 17):

if anyone is still looking for a solution that does not Subclass the `EditText`:

(Code is in kotlin)

```
    editText.setAccessibilityDelegate(object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, eventType: Int) {
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED){
                // here you can access selection of the editText 
                // with `editText.selectionStart`
                // and `editText.selectionEnd``
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: wow, it works perfect.. but the docs say that " If accessibility is not
             * enabled this method has no effect."

Comment: @mifthi You can use `sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked` as it does not check if accessibility is enabled

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work everywhere. At least Samsung SM-T580 with Android 8.1 doesn't receive this call (though it works on vanilla Android 8.1).

Comment: @ookami.kb did you use the `sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked` version?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari yep, tried both of them. For vanilla Android `sendAccessibilityEvent` is called, but for Samsung – none of them.

Comment: Tested on Android 9, Samsung device, and `sendAccessibilityEvent` is not called.

Comment: in java if someone need it
editor.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate(){      
         @Override
         public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
              super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
              if (eventType == android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED){
                 
       
            
               } else {
    
  }
          }
     });

Answer (score 13):

I debugged a related problem across different versions of Android (feel free to comment on your findings and I'll add them to the list).

Summary of findings:

---

4.1.6 (Samsung device)

`onSelectionChanged()` gets called on TEXT EDITS only.

---

4.0.6 (HTC Device)

4.0.4 (reported by user Arch1tect on Samsung Note 1 device)

`onSelectionChanged()` gets called on cursor changes (clicks, moves etc) but NOT on Text Edits.

---

In the cases above where you are not informed of the section changes (text edits in some versions of Android), you will have to do that using a `TextWatcher`, for example in the `afterTextChanged()` method.

Comment: I found same issue: Samsung 4.04 (Note 1) : onSelectionChanged() gets called on cursor changes (clicks, moves etc) but NOT on Text Edits.

Answer (score 11):

Oh goodness, thanks so much for this idea. There's absolutely no reason why this feature shouldn't be in the SDK. I have an quick subclass that implements this idea but adding on the additional feature of listeners for when the selection changes. Hope it's useful.

```
public class EditTextSelectable extends EditText {

    public interface OnSelectionChangedListener {
         public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd);
    }

    private List<onSelectionChangedListener> listeners
        = new ArrayList<onSelectionChangedListener>();

    public void addOnSelectionChangedListener(OnSelectionChangedListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeOnSelectionChangedListener(OnSelectionChangedListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        for (onSelectionChangedListener l : listeners)
            l.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);     
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi could you help tell me how to set the OnSelectionChangedListener in the activity ?

Comment: @SWAppDev `editText.addOnSelectionChangedListener(this)`



Don't forget implement your activity from `EditTextSelectable.onSelectionChangedListener`

Answer (score 4):

The java version of the above answer,

```
mEtEditor.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate(){
        /**
         * Sends an accessibility event of the given type. If accessibility is not
         * enabled this method has no effect.
         * <p>
         * The default implementation behaves as {@link View#sendAccessibilityEvent(int)
         * View#sendAccessibilityEvent(int)} for the case of no accessibility delegate
         * been set.
         * </p>
         *
         * @param host      The View hosting the delegate.
         * @param eventType The type of the event to send.
         * @see View#sendAccessibilityEvent(int) View#sendAccessibilityEvent(int)
         */
        @Override
        public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED){
                // here you can access selection of the editText
                // with `editText.selectionStart`
                // and `editText.selectionEnd``                    
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `Extension` version of what [@Saeed Entezari posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440575/821173):

```
fun EditText.setSelectionChangedListener(onSelectionChangedListener: (editText: EditText, selectionStart: Int, selectionEnd: Int) -> Unit) {
    setAccessibilityDelegate(object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, eventType: Int) {
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED){
                val editText = this@setSelectionChangedListener
                onSelectionChangedListener.invoke(editText, editText.selectionStart, editText.selectionEnd)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Question asker originally posted their answer into the question. I'm moving it into an answer to keep the question and answer separated.

***Step One: Create the sub class***

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditTextCursorWatcher extends EditText {

    public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }


     @Override   
     protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) { 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "selStart is " + selStart + "selEnd is " + selEnd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } 
}
```

***Step Two:*** refer to the class in the layout file (eg main.xml (though mine was a custom dialog layout)).  Don't forget to use full package name (in this case com.example.EditTextCursorWatcher, eg

```
    <com.example.EditTextCursorWatcher
     android:id="@+id/etEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
editText.doAfterTextChanged {
    doSomething(editText.selectionStart , editText.selectionEnd)  
}

editText.setOnClickListener {
    doSomething(editText.selectionStart , editText.selectionEnd)  
}
```