# I want to be able to get the starting and ending position of selected text inside of an EditText field in Android

Tags: android

```
binding.description.setLongClickable(true);
binding.description.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            int start = binding.description.getSelectionStart();
            int end = binding.description.getSelectionEnd();
            Log.e(TAG, "Start:" + start + " End:" + end);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This allows me to get the start and end position as the user long presses the EditText but I'm not sure what event I should listen to as the user readjusts the start and end position of the markers.

Basically, I want to allow a user to select a piece of text and I will know the start and end of that text within the EditText.

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962366/android-edittext-listener-for-cursor-position-change

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you.