# why I'm getting error while extending EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Actually I'm trying to extend `editText` for adding `cursorChangedListener` by referencng [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137700/8027365) but I don't know why I'm getting error while using that in activity.I've tried to reference some related questions but none of them were helpful.I wonder where the problem is and why it's showing error . When I removed the listener part from the `EditTextSelectable`class it didn't give any error but adding the `selectionChange` part giving the error.

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
EditTextSelectable editTxt=findViewById(R.id.editTxt);
 editTxt.addOnSelectionChangedListener(new 
 EditTextSelectable.onSelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selStart+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:ignore="NamespaceTypo">


<community.testing.EditTextSelectable
    android:id="@+id/editTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class EditTextSelectable extends EditText {

public interface onSelectionChangedListener {

     void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd);
}



private List<onSelectionChangedListener> listeners;

public EditTextSelectable(Context context) {
    super(context);
    listeners = new ArrayList<onSelectionChangedListener>();
}

public EditTextSelectable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    listeners = new ArrayList<onSelectionChangedListener>();
}

public EditTextSelectable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    listeners = new ArrayList<onSelectionChangedListener>();
}

public void addOnSelectionChangedListener(onSelectionChangedListener o) {
    listeners.add(o);
}

protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    for (onSelectionChangedListener l : listeners)
        l.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

}
```

}

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{community.testing/community.testing.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class community.testing.EditTextSelectable
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class community.testing.EditTextSelectable
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                   at community.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                   at community.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                   at community.testing.EditTextSelectable.onSelectionChanged(EditTextSelectable.java:47)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7340)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8907)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
                                                                   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
                                                                   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
                                                                   at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3684)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
                                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1213)
                                                                   at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
                                                                   at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56)
                                                                   at community.testing.EditTextSelectable.<init>(EditTextSelectable.java:33)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                   at community.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: add layout entry .

Comment: I've added the xml part sir @HemantParmar

Comment: You sure that `community.testing.EditTextSelectable` is fully qualified name for `EditTextSelectable` ?

Comment: @user8027365 test case try this `public class EditTextSelectable extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`

Comment: tell EditTextSelectable  class package name.

Comment: @user8027365 post `MainActivity` code as well

Comment: @HemantParmar community.testing;

Comment: @MikeM. yes I did

Comment: your edittext method `onSelectionChanged` is not parent  method make it override.

Comment: @HemantParmar no it hasn't solved the issue

Comment: @user8027365 where are you using the method `addOnSelectionChangedListener`?

Comment: @y.allam check my Edit

Comment: Okay Can anyone please post any New code for cursonListener

Comment: Just add `if (listeners != null)` before the `for` in `onSelectionChanged()`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks sir it worked like a charm please add your comment as an answer to the question

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I should've seen it earlier.

Comment: @MikeM. no problem at all